# What is the purpose of having WelcomeViewController in Anypic(ios,Parse)

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I wonder what is the purpose of having a WelcomeViewController in Anypic since their is no WelcomeView associated with it. It checks if currentUser exists, if no then LoginViewController is presented, if yes then proceed to TabBarController. Why not putting the logic in WelcomeViewController to AppDelegate, or just create an empty ViewController as what is done is AnyWall app?
Thank you
Zach

Answer (score 0):

By following the code in GitHub, the best answer i can give you is that they do this to get order in their application design. If like you said they placed all the code into the app delegate, then the `AppDelegate` will be messy and un-ordered (you can see that `WelcomeView` has a lot of functionality code).

There is no right and wrong, if the code works then the code works. But if your code if built in a good design, you will have a lot less work if you wish to alter something in the future.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with the point putting all the code into the delegate will make it messy, what I am wondering is(kinda newbie question) if creating a UIViewController that has no view associated with it is a good practice when programming ObjectC?

Comment: A UIViewController that has no view associated with it is not a proper description. The WelcomeViewController is a controller of a view & is responsible on presenting other views. That is perfectly acceptable in MVC diagram. It can cause more problems if you are doing so & not following the MVC rules.